# Oracle calculate YTD ,PYTD, QTD , PQTD , MTD, PMTD

Tags: sql, oracle

My query is

```
select 
ENTRIES,
SUM( CASE WHEN to_char(to_date(record_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd'),'YYYY') =2020
                 THEN ENTRIES END )         AS "Curr Yr ENTRIES" ,
SUM( CASE WHEN to_char(to_date(record_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd'),'YYYY') =2019
                 THEN ENTRIES END )         AS "PREV Yr ENTRIES" ,
SUM( CASE WHEN to_char(to_date(record_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd'),'MM') =11
                 THEN ENTRIES END ) AS "Current Month ENTRIES" ,
SUM( CASE WHEN to_char(to_date(record_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd'),'MM') =10
                 THEN ENTRIES END ) AS "PREV Month ENTRIES" ,
SUM( CASE WHEN to_char(to_date(record_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd'),'MM') =09
                 THEN ENTRIES END ) AS "PREV TO PREV Month ENTRIES" ,
SUM( CASE WHEN to_char(to_date(record_date,'yyyy/mm/dd'), 'Q')=4
                 THEN ENTRIES END ) AS "Curr Qtr ENTRIES"  ,
SUM( CASE WHEN to_char(to_date(record_date,'yyyy/mm/dd'), 'Q')=3
                 THEN ENTRIES END ) AS "PREV Qtr ENTRIES" 
from market
group by ENTRIES
```

Im new to oracle and in my query i have hard coded the values of year ,month and quarter.
But i want my query to work without giving any value so that it automatically picks value
let me know how can it be done.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please edit your question (using the `edit` button below the question tags) and explain what your acronyms PYTD, QTD, PQTD, and PMTD mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT ENTRIES,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN record_date >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' )
         AND  record_date <  ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' ), 12 )
         THEN ENTRIES
         END
       ) AS "Curr Yr ENTRIES",
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN record_date >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' ), -12 )
         AND  record_date <  TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' )
         THEN ENTRIES
         END
       ) AS "Prev Yr ENTRIES",
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN record_date >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
         AND  record_date <  ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 1 )
         THEN ENTRIES
         END
       ) AS "Curr Month ENTRIES",
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN record_date >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), -1 )
         AND  record_date <  TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
         THEN ENTRIES
         END
       ) AS "Prev Month ENTRIES",
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN record_date >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'Q' )
         AND  record_date <  ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'Q' ), 3 )
         THEN ENTRIES
         END
       ) AS "Curr Qtr ENTRIES",
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN record_date >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'Q' ), -3 )
         AND  record_date <  TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'Q' )
         THEN ENTRIES
         END
       ) AS "Prev Qtr ENTRIES"
from market
group by ENTRIES
```

*(Although I'm not convinced you want the initial `ENTRIES,` in the `SELECT` clause or the final `GROUP BY` and, instead, could just `SUM` over the entire period.)*